# Proving representation of the same coset in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ iff elements are congruent modulo $5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic, quotient-group

**Problem Statement**

Prove that $a + bi$ and $a' + b'i$ represent the same cosets in $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ iff $a \equiv a' (\text{mod 5})$ and $b \equiv b' (\text{mod 5})$

---

**Definitions**

$\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{ a + bi \mid a,b, \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

$(5) = \{5a + 5bi \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

---

**Relevant Facts**

Lemma: Let $G$ be a group, $H < G$ a subgroup and for all $g_1,g_2 \in G$ the following are equivalent:

1. $g_1, g_2$ belong to the same left coset of $H$
2. $g_1 H = g_2 H$
3. $g_2^{-1}g_2 \in H$

---

**My Attempt**

This being an 'if an only if' statement we need to prove the conclusion from the predicate ($\Rightarrow$) and the predicate from the conclusion ($\Leftarrow$). However, given the nature of my misunderstanding I would like to focus solely on the forward statement and address some questions I have there that I believe will carry over to the reverse statement. To that end:

$\Rightarrow$ Suppose $(a+bi),(a'+b'i)$ belong to the same coset of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ Then by the above Lemma that means that:

1. $(a+bi) + (5) = (a'+b'i) + (5)$
2. $-(a+bi)+(a'+b'i) = (-a-bi)+(a'+b'i) = (a'-a) + (b'-b)i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$

Now, elements of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ have the form: $$z + (5) = (c+di) + (5f + 5gi) = (c+5f) + (d + 5g)i,\ \text{where}\ c,d,f,g,5 \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Which can be written more succinctly as $$ k + ni,\ \text{where}\ k,n \in \mathbb{Z}$$ Since $(c + 5f), (d + 5g) \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now the statement $t \equiv t' (\text{mod}\ 5)$ implies that $t-t' = 5s,\ s \in \mathbb{Z}$

So we have: $$(a'-a) + (b'-b)i = 5q + (5s)i = k + ni$$ If $a \equiv a' (\text{mod}\ 5)$ and $b \equiv b' (\text{mod}\ 5)$

---

**Questions/Concerns**

My main concern here is that it seems that the inclusion $(a'-a) + (b'-b)i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ doesn't really rely on the fact that $a,b$ are congruent modulo $5$ to their primed counterparts. Rather, as long as $a,a',b,b' \in \mathbb{Z}$ then we have our inclusion. Is it the case that I've messed up the form for an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$? I wanted to pull the $5$'s out of each factor in the resultant sum: $(c+5f) + (d + 5g)i = 5(\frac{c}{5} + f) + 5(\frac{d}{5} + g)i$ as that would have the same sort of form as the implied expression of congruence modulo $5$ i.e., $t \equiv t' (\text{mod}\ 5) \implies t-t' = 5s,\ s \in \mathbb{Z}$ however the sums in the parentheses $(\frac{c}{5} + f)$ and $(\frac{d}{5} + g)$ would, in general, not be integers, where the divisors $5s$ are necessarily integers.

What am I missing here? Or am I on the complete wrong track for this part of the proof?

Comment: (1) It was hard to see the intention of the statement 'So we have: $(a'-a) + (b'-b)i = 5q + (5s)i = k + ni$ If $a \equiv a' (\text{mod}\ 5)$ and $b \equiv b' (\text{mod}\ 5)$'
(2) Is the statement '$(a'-a) + (b'-b)i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$' meant to be  $(a'-a) + (b'-b)i \in (5)$?

Comment: @aerile Yep. Complete oversight and error on my part. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is simply a misapplication of the lemma you quote, the condition that $a+bi + (5) = a'+b'i + (5)$ is equivalent to the statement that $-(a+bi)+(a'+b'i) \in (5)$ (this lemma is sometimes referred to as the "coset criterion"). This should make your analysis much more straightforward.

Note that if the version of the lemma you were applying were true, it would force *every* element of the quotient ring to be identified. This is a good "sanity check" when you're doing a proof to see if you've made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is. I'm not sure how I made that sort of oversight as I've used that lemma properly a few times now but that makes perfect sense, and I can easily see now how my algebra will fit into this criterion. Thank you for your response.